# Do I need Austrian and German transit visa if I have Bosnian tourist visa?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, bosnia

I'm Egyptian and I have Bosnian tourist visa, if I travel by Austrian airlines Cairo-Vienna-Sarajevo and back by Lufthansa Sarajevo-Munich-Cairo do I need transit or any kind of visa for Vienna and Munich?

Comment: The Bosnian visa doesn't help you, I don't think.  I don't know whether Egyptians require an airport transit visa in Austria or Germany, but we have another question that should point you toward the answer.